# what is the origin or etymology of the expression "ni madres"

Tags: etimología

I'm guessing it's an abbreviation for something similar in English to when we swear 'not on your mother' meaning 'not on your mother's grave'

Comment: I'm not from Mexico so I can't be sure but I think that "ni madres" doesn't come from a longer sentence. It seems that Mexicans use "madre" as synonym of a wide range of things and they've got a lot of expressions that include that word https://unamglobal.unam.mx/la-bendita-palabra-madre/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No vas muy desencaminado. En español existía la costumbre, bastante extendida, de jurar por el padre o por la madre, estuvieran estos vivos o muertos, para evidenciar que algo era verdadero, así se decía "Te lo juro por mi madre (que yo...)", "Te lo juro por la tumba de mi madre (que no...)" o "Te lo juro por mi padre (que no he ido...)", como juramento sagrado sobre el que prevalecía cualquier otra cosa "falsa" que se hubiera dicho en contra. También esta expresión era utilizada como amenaza "Por tu padre (te juro) que hoy no sales", "Por tu madre (te juro) que hoy no ves a ese chico" .

Así la oración, "ni madre" o "ni madres" en plural, era exclamada para decir o dar de forma directa un "**no rotundo**" de manera brusca y un tanto ruda como respuesta, vendría de aquellas locuciones más antiguas pero en un sentido opuesto, "**Ni** aunque lo jures por tu **madre** te voy a creer", es decir, "No te creo en absoluto", en definitiva "No". El plural va más allá, y procede de la misma retórica, "**Ni** por todas las **madres** del mundo vas a salir hoy de fiesta sino haces antes los deberes", que es la forma más sagrada de negarse o decir ¡No! y sirve para declarar rotundamente un **¡No!** en toda regla si antes no cumplías la condición impuesta.

Al final estas frases de juramentos y amenazas acabaron en "Ni por tu madre (lo hago)", "Ni por todas las madres del mundo (lo hago)" para llegar a "Ni madres" y escenificar un "No" expreso y rotundo de rechazo hacia algo.

Ejemplos;

- Me prestas la moto, ¡Ni madres!
- Me das dinero ¡Ni madres!
- Vienes mañana a cazar ¡Ni madre!

**P.D.** Vendría a expresar casi lo mismo que las frases ¡Ni loco!, ¡Ni harto de vino!, ¡Ni por todo el oro del mundo!, para negar o no hacer algo de forma expresa y rotunda.

Comment: La expresión "ni madres" es propia de México. No veo ahí en tu texto ninguna mención al respecto ni he podido encontrar referencia alguna que indique que es una abreviación como pareces dar a entender.